# using coalesce doubles the number of records returns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries below. The 1st query returns 83 rows and is what I expect. Query 2 though returns 166 rows (so double the 1st query). The only difference is shown below in the select statement in both of pf and pc,

Query 1
    Sedol

Query 2
    Coalesce(ISIN, Sedol, BbergTicker) Id

I do not understand why this doubles the number of rows returned?

**Query 1**

```
;with pf as
(
    select Name, Sedol, Nominal, FundCode, FileCode 
    from tbl1L where FundCode = 'BUNM' and CashItem = 0 and FileCode in ('MAIN', 'REISTD')
), pc as
(
    select Name, Sedol, Nominal, FundCode, FileCode 
from tbl1C where FundCode = 'BUNM' and CashItem = 0 and FileCode in ('MAIN', 'REDIST')
)
select coalesce(pf.FundCode, pc.FundCode) Fund, coalesce(pf.FileCode, pc.FileCode) FileCode, 
coalesce(pf.Name, pc.Name) Name, coalesce(pf.Sedol, pc.Sedol) Sedol, 
isnull(pf.Nominal, 0) PfNom, isnull(pc.Nominal, 0) PcNom, 
isnull(isnull(pf.Nominal, 0) - isnull(pc.Nominal, 0), -999) NomDiff
from pf full outer join pc on pf.Sedol = pc.Sedol and pf.FileCode = pc.FileCode 
where isnull(isnull(pf.Nominal, 0) - isnull(pc.Nominal, 0),-999) <> 0
```

**Query 2**

```
;with pf as
(
    select Name, Coalesce(ISIN, Sedol, BbergTicker) Id, Nominal, FundCode, FileCode 
    from tbl1L where FundCode = 'BUNM' and CashItem = 0 and FileCode in ('MAIN', 'REISTD')
), pc as
(
    select Name, Coalesce(ISIN, Sedol, BbergTicker) Id, Nominal, FundCode, FileCode 
from tbl1C where FundCode = 'BUNM' and CashItem = 0 and FileCode in ('MAIN', 'REDIST')
)
select coalesce(pf.FundCode, pc.FundCode) Fund, coalesce(pf.FileCode, pc.FileCode) FileCode, 
coalesce(pf.Name, pc.Name) Name, coalesce(pf.Id, pc.Id) Id, coalesce(pf.Sedol, pc.Sedol) Sedol, 
isnull(pf.Nominal, 0) PfNom, isnull(pc.Nominal, 0) PcNom, 
isnull(isnull(pf.Nominal, 0) - isnull(pc.Nominal, 0), -999) NomDiff
from pf full outer join pc on pf.Id = pc.Id and pf.FileCode = pc.FileCode 
where isnull(isnull(pf.Nominal, 0) - isnull(pc.Nominal, 0),-999) <> 0
```

Comment: In the second query, you still have this `coalesce(pf.Sedol, pc.Sedol) `, but none of the CTEs directly above it have a column output called `sedol`. Is your code all of the code, or did you format it for us?

Comment: Look at the results of pf and pc in the second example. They must generate duplicate Id values.

Comment: Don't be scared to add some white space to your queries so they are not a wall of text. As posted this in nearly impossible to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Query 1 :**

```
pf.Sedol = pc.Sedol and pf.FileCode = pc.FileCode
```

**Query 2 :**

```
pf.Id = pc.Id and pf.FileCode = pc.FileCode
```

In joins there is a difference in both queries .

Coalesce will not impact count in records